# A problem on non-commutative ring

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a non-commutative ring with $1$ and $a,b\in R$ such that $ab=1 \neq ba.$ Could anyone advise me on how to show there exists $c\in R-\{b\}$ such that $ac=1 \ ?$

Hints will suffice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a homomorphism of groups $R \rightarrow R$ which is multiplication by $a$ on the left, i.e. $x \mapsto ax$. Then $1$ and $ba$ have the same image.

Then you can conclude...

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how this lead to the conclusion. Could you explain?

Comment: Then it is a non-injective homomorphism. Thus for any element in the image, the preimage has more than one element. Since $1$ is the image (it is reached by $b$), you have that $1$ is reached by more than one element.

Comment: But non-injective doesn't necessarily imply EVERY element in the image has more than one element in preimage? Also, how have you made use of the fact that $ba \neq 1 \ ?$

Comment: I used $ba \neq 1$ to show the map is not injective, since both $1$ and $ba$ are mapped to $a$. It tells you the map is not injective. Now you are right, since it is not injective, every element in the image has more than one element in the preimage. In particular, $1$ is in the image since $b \mapsto 1$, and it tells you all the coset $b + ker$ is mapped to $1$.